# Parsing WSDL Issue in PHP

Tags: php, apache, wsdl

I have a WSDL for a service provider that sits locally on my Apache instance and is referenced by my PHP application.  However, when my scripts call the WSDL, I'm seeing the error below in the Apache logs and the script fails:

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from  
'https://x.x.com/MyWSDL.wsdl' : failed to load external entity
"https://x.x.com/MyWSDL.wsdl"\n in /SCRIPTS/SCRIPTS_myscripts.php
on line 112
```

I can access the WSDL externally using a browser with no issue.  I can also access it locally from the linux server (using lynx) with no issue.  What is odd is I have this exact same setup working on another box (just older versions of PHP and Apache).  Wondering if there's something new in the PHP config I'm overlooking?  Not even sure how to continue troubleshooting this since I can download the WSDL externally and internally using that URL.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

UPDATE:
After doing a little more digging, I've discovered this is somehow related to mod_security.  If I disable mod_security, the soap call works without issue.  I've tried to determine how to create a mod_security exception for this but I'm not coming up with much.  Really don't want to turn the entire module off.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommenting this line in your php.ini: extension=php_openssl.dll

Hope that helps!